# How to start a Console App as running under the System Windows user account?

Tags: c#, .net, process, createprocessasuser

I tried

```
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = filename,
        UserName = "System",
        UseShellExecute = false,
    },
};

process.Start();
```

but it yields

> Win32Exception was unhandled
>
> Login failed: unknown user name or wrong password

I will have to use `CreateProcessAsUser`?
How can I get the appropriate parameters to pass to that method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The System accounts password is maintained interally by Windows (I think) i.e. attempting to start a process as the System account by supplying credentials in this way is ultimately destined to failure.

I did however find a forum post that describes a neat trick that can be used to run processes under the system account by (ab)using windows services:

[Tip: Run process in system account (sc.exe)](http://forum.sysinternals.com/tip-run-process-in-system-account-scexe_topic16714.html)

Alternatively the Windows Sysinternals tool [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) appears to allow you to run a process under the System account by using the `-s` switch.

Comment: `psexec -s` is my usual approach. Remember that `psexec` does require an elevated launcher itself.

Answer (score 0):

The Username should be `LocalSystem` if you want to run your process with high privileges (it's a member of Administrators group) or `LocalService` for normal privileges

EDIT: My mistake LocalSystem & LocalService are not regulary users and, therefore, they cannot be provided as a username. Kragen's solution is the right one